# Power Query: format date become automatically serial number when refreshing query with opened sources

Tags: powerquery

I have a query that gets data from a folder. this folder contains 2 Excel file (xlsb) with some date columns.

When I open the file source 1, and refresh my query, the format date of file 1 automatically become serial number (15/06/2015 becomes 38518) while the format of file source 2 is still date DD/MM/YYYY (file 2 is not opened).

Power Query cannot convert the format of this column to date DD/MM/YYYY. I have this problem only when the source is opened.

Could you please help me with it?
Thanks
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7INWV.png)

thank you very much

Here is the code :

```
let  Source = Folder.Files("H:\Test"),
Refresh_When_Excel_Source_Opened = Table.SelectRows(Source, each not Text.StartsWith([Name], "~$")),
Add_Get_Data_From_Content_Column = Table.AddColumn(Refresh_When_Excel_Source_Opened, "Get_Data_From_Content", each Excel.Workbook([Content])),
Keep_Only_Get_Data_From_Content_Column = Table.SelectColumns(Add_Get_Data_From_Content_Column,{"Get_Data_From_Content"}),
Expand_Get_Data_Column = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Keep_Only_Get_Data_From_Content_Column, "Get_Data_From_Content", {"Name", "Data"}, {"Get_Data.Name", "Get_Data.Data"}),
Filter_Only_BDD_Tables = Table.SelectRows(Expand_Get_Data_Column, each Text.StartsWith([Get_Data.Name], "BDD")),
Expand_Composed_Data = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Filter_Only_BDD_Tables, "Get_Data.Data", {"Statut", "Secteur du juge", "Référence Juge", "Code IODAS ", "Code GED", "Nom", "Prénom", "Genre", "Date de naissance", "Référent TS", "Référent administratif", "Date admission au SEMNA", "Type de mesure en cours", "Date du début de la mesure", "Date de fin de la  mesure", "Lieu de placement actuel", "Echéance CSS", "Observations CPAM", "Date envoi du kit APJM", "Date de dépôt de la demande SG", "Notification SEJM", "Compte bancaire", "Observations diverses", "Date de notification de Reconnaissance MDPH", "Dossier PPE ", "Dossier DDE TDS déposé", "Date de dépôt", "Dépôt de DDE TDS à Paris", "Type de titre", "Réponse préfecture", "Autres démarches liées au séjour", "Démarches état civil auprès du pays origine ou consulat", "Observations"}, {"Statut", "Secteur du juge", "Référence Juge", "Code IODAS ", "Code GED", "Nom", "Prénom", "Genre", "Date de naissance", "Référent TS", "Référent administratif", "Date admission au SEMNA", "Type de mesure en cours", "Date du début de la mesure", "Date de fin de la  mesure", "Lieu de placement actuel", "Echéance CSS", "Observations CPAM", "Date envoi du kit APJM", "Date de dépôt de la demande SG", "Notification SEJM", "Compte bancaire", "Observations diverses", "Date de notification de Reconnaissance MDPH", "Dossier PPE ", "Dossier DDE TDS déposé", "Date de dépôt", "Dépôt de DDE TDS à Paris", "Type de titre", "Réponse préfecture", "Autres démarches liées au séjour", "Démarches état civil auprès du pays origine ou consulat", "Observations"}),
#"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(Expand_Composed_Data, {{Table.ColumnNames(Expand_Composed_Data){0},"Pôle"}}),
Change_Data_Type = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Renamed Columns",{{"Statut", type text}, {"Secteur du juge", type text}, {"Référence Juge", type text}, {"Code IODAS ", type text}, {"Code GED", type text}, {"Nom", type text}, {"Prénom", type text}, {"Genre", type text}, {"Date de naissance", type date}, {"Référent TS", type text}, {"Référent administratif", type text}, {"Date admission au SEMNA", type date}, {"Type de mesure en cours", type text}, {"Date du début de la mesure", type date}, {"Date de fin de la  mesure", type date}, {"Lieu de placement actuel", type text}, {"Echéance CSS", type date}, {"Observations CPAM", type text}, {"Date envoi du kit APJM", type date}, {"Date de dépôt de la demande SG", type date}, {"Notification SEJM", type text}, {"Compte bancaire", type text}, {"Observations diverses", type text}, {"Date de notification de Reconnaissance MDPH", type date}}),
Exclude_Headers_Other_Columns = Table.SelectRows(Change_Data_Type, each [Statut] <> "Statut"),
Keep_Only_Necessary_Columns = Table.SelectColumns(Exclude_Headers_Other_Columns,{"Pôle","Statut", "Secteur du juge", "Référence Juge", "Code IODAS ", "Code GED", "Nom", "Prénom", "Genre", "Date de naissance", "Référent TS", "Référent administratif", "Date admission au SEMNA", "Type de mesure en cours", "Date du début de la mesure", "Date de fin de la  mesure", "Lieu de placement actuel", "Echéance CSS", "Observations CPAM", "Date envoi du kit APJM", "Date de dépôt de la demande SG", "Notification SEJM", "Compte bancaire", "Observations diverses", "Date de notification de Reconnaissance MDPH"})
in Keep_Only_Necessary_Columns
```

Comment: What format are both files ? MM/DD/YY or DD/MM/YY    Also edit your question and paste in the code you are using in your query from home..advanced editor...

Comment: here is the code :

Comment: Sorry the code is too long. I have just added the code into my post

Comment: the format is DD/MM/YYYY for both file. I haven't any problem when these 2 source files are closed. but when one of them is opened, I have that problem

Comment: Perhaps someone else will help then. Assuming the file format does not change between initial setup (buffered preview) and later refresh , then I can't see how code would evaluate differently if source file is open